# AngularJS scope does not notice change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `$scope` field that I use for a `ng-src` attribute in an `<img>:`

```
$scope.imageDataUrl
```

The field is initialized as follows:

```
$scope.myJsWrapper = new MyJsWrapper();
$scope.myJsWrapper.getImageUrl(function (imageDataUrl) {
    $scope.imageDataUrl = imageDataUrl;
});
```

Here the external JS function:

```
function MyJsWrapper() {
    this.getImageUrl = function (withImage) {
        thirdPartyJsFile.getData().then(function (data) {
            var imageDataUrl = thirdPartyJsFile.getDataUrl(data, "image/png");
            if (withImage) {
                withImage(imageDataUrl);
            }
         });
    }
}
```

It is a complicated way, but the third party app forces me to do it that way.
The problem I have is that somehow angular does not notice the change of the field `imageDataUrl`. So the image is not updated.
I tried even `$scope.$watch` for that field but it wasn't triggered.
Funny enough it changes when I scroll in the browser or click anywhere (as well the `$scope.$watch`).

Why does angular not recognize the field change and what do I need to do so it works?

Comment: Did you try call `$scope.$apply()` after change image source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it is a thirdy party library that is updating your `$scope`, to let angular context to be aware of your change you need to call `$scope.$apply()`

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.imageDataUrl = imageDataUrl;
});
```

in your callback

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of
>   the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the AngularJS framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.